# lua function to avoid pre-defined circles from overlapping

Tags: function, lua, overlapping

I hope I can get some help here.
I have four circles with each radius of 25mm. I want them to spread on a 520x 520 circular screen without overlapping each other. I tried using math.random () for their x and y location but they quite often overlap each other. Can someone help me with a function which can define the coordinates of each of these circles without overlapping.

Regards,
Ed

Comment: Can I please get some direction?

Comment: Check each new circle for overlapping with already existing circles (measure the distance between circle centers).  Generate each new circle until it would not intersect.

Comment: Thanks Egor - really appreciate it